# What are good apps to help with VFR navigation on my first solo?

Tags: flight-training, navigation, visual-flight-rules

Currently I am a student pilot in Spain (Barcelona) and I am 2 days away from my solo. I wanted to ask if there is any good application that will help me on VFR navigation since I'm allowed to go to all Barcelona in my solo, but I am afraid if I get lost I see my self weak in VFR flights and specially to locate my position so any good app in the iPhone device that will help me in navigation because I want to visit the whole Barcelona and not just staying at places that I know because I will get bored for sure.

Comment: If you get lost then I can guarantee you will immediately stop being bored :-) Seriously, this is a question for your flight instructor. He should only allow you to fly in conditions that you're properly trained and competent in, and if you are weak in navigation then you should fix that first with him. An app by itself won't help you navigate any better unless you know how to use it.

Comment: lol yeah i can manage that but i want to make sure i'm safe you know what i mean that's why i asked for some apps that will help me on my nav

Comment: If you can't be safe without an app, then you are not ready to do what you are planning to do.  You should tell this to your instructor.  Your first solo is not a time to go sight seeing, and if you think your first solo will be boring, then you should think about why you want to fly.

Comment: @Pondlife  I would argue that even being able to use the app will not fix underlying weaknesses in aviate, navigate, communicate.

Comment: "I want to visit the whole Barcelona" - [Don't be this guy](https://assets.digital.cabinet-office.gov.uk/media/56bc467440f0b613d100001c/Pegasus_Quik_G-XJJM_02-16.pdf)

Comment: @DanHulme yeah man what i can do 50 hours solo at least i can do something that makes the time pass quickly. or you want me to stay doing circuits for the whole 50 hours lol

Comment: Just because you do something on your first solo doesn't mean you have to do only the exact same thing every other time. Why would you want to put yourself in an unfamiliar situation with an unfamiliar app your first time?

Comment: There is a difference between flying solo and your first solo. Which are you asking about? Your first solo should ONLY be circuits. If your instructor tells you different, then ask why. If you are asking about solo flying before you qualify, you should be only be doing flights you have planned 100%. Do not use an app, or start random sight seeing until at least you have passed your exam.  Learn to fly with a map, a watch and a compass first.  Then think about GPS and apps.  "Plan the fly" and "fly the plan".  Too many dead pilots didn't listen to advice.  Please don't be one of them.

Comment: Does your aircraft have a GPS installed? All you would need then is to know how to push the Direct-To button and follow a heading.

Comment: What will you do if the battery on whatever device you are using suddenly goes flat? You shouldn't even think about leaving the circuit and training area by yourself until you have been taught to properly navigate. But perhaps you should make it clearer that you are asking about flight planning and navigation apps, because they do exist.

Comment: @Ben i'm not that stupid Ben to depend only on my Phone, i will plan everything as normal procedures is saying but i will keep the phone as a backup not as the main navigation just to track my progress and my performance

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the downvote here. This question is based on what a pilot is planning to do. While the title question is too broad, he narrows it down in the body. His plan, as stated, may be a bad one, but that doesn't make the question bad.

Comment: Even without a GPS, all sorts of things can happen to maps and to compasses. Are all the critics sure that they are able to navigate without map and compass? Also, in the US, we are taught the lost art of lost procedures: climb, communicate, confess, comply, as well as how to call PAN PAN/MAYDAY on 121.5, and how to ask for "DF" (direction finding) from Flight Service. Perception of OPs aeronautical decision-making, I laud him for asking the question before getting in the aircraft.

Comment: If he be asking if there were something for the iPhone in case all else fails, there would be many answers. Even Google maps would suffice. When the question is for something to help in navigation, there is nothing. If every navigation system died. i'd whip out my iphone or ipad and use Personal Black Box for emergency use but I would not rely on that in an a/c if I had a single VOR functioning.

Answer (score 14):

No, there is no "app" you should be seeking at this stage of your training to do what you're asking about.

First, if you have questions about what you'll be doing while you're flying solo and how you'll be navigating, you should be discussing this with your instructor, not on an internet message board.

Second, whatever tools you'll use in flight need to be ones that you've used under supervision of an instructor, so that you understand how to use them, and what their limitations are.  Student solo flying is NOT the time to go exploring technology and apps you've not used before, in addition to the **full-time** tasks of maintaining aircraft control, aviating, navigating, and communicating.  Too many dead pilots got focused on some technological toy and, without realizing it, lost situational awareness and/or control of their aircraft.

Third, before you are navigating anywhere solo, you need to be able to (and demonstrate to your instructor that you can) navigate successfully with the tools you have -- a map, compass, stopwatch, and the pre-flight planning you've done.  If you don't feel up to that task (which has been all of us early on in our training -- nobody is born with a built-in INS), work on those skills ***with an instructor***.  Navigation apps are fine, but they supplement, rather than substitute for, your own skills when it comes to VFR navigation.

Fourth, the fact that you would come here to pose such a question, rather than to your instructor, is troublesome: you want an app that can enable you to go off on adventures sightseeing all of Barcelona, but you aren't discussing these plans with your instructor... perhaps he might not approve of all that you're planning?  Perhaps, maybe, you should limit your expectations of how much adventuring & exploring you'll undertake initially, and have a more complete discussion with your instructor of what you are, and are not, expected to do when, or if, you are signed off to solo.  (As stated in comments, the initial solo is typically pattern work only, rather than navigation.)

Flying is about far more than aircraft control; it is a matter of judgement as well, and the difference between sound judgement and the lack of same can make the difference between a successful or a catastrophic outcome of a flight, at least as much as the difference between great and mediocre "stick & rudder" skills.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't do something that you are not used to do at your first solo. First solo is always something you are waiting for, may be from the first day of your flying. So,I hope, it will not be that boring. It is not a good idea at all to depend upon a app when you are flying your 1st VFR solo. Please take enough preparation considering the terrain around your flying areas/routes. Search in Google map/earth to be very specific. Take enough preparation on the use of radio aids and diversion procedures. Be confident about emergencies. And, enjoy your solo. Good luck!!! Have a safe flight.

Comment: yep you are totaly right i agree with you but what i mean is for my others solo not the first one of course, i will prepare everything as you sais of course! just i tought that it will be always good to use a backup to track my progress and make sure i'm in the right path this why i asked for a navigation app maybe some of the Private Pilot are using them to choose the best one. Thank you :)

Comment: Google Maps is **not** a flight planning tool. To check the terrain clearances and controlled airspaces you need to use the map issued by your country's civil aviation authority. This will probably be a paper map in early navigation flights.

Comment: Yes Google map is not a flight planning tool.. but u should understand that in charts only the obstacles are maked with height.. you can check those in google to have visual understanding.. Thats what I did mean @ Dan Hulme

Answer (score 0):

In a solo, you shouldn't be doing anything you haven't already done with an instructor onboard, but without his assistance. If you haven't navigated the trip you plan to fly solo yet without your instructor doing the navigation for you, then you aren't ready to solo.